# How do I flatten a selection of a terrain map?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, edit-mode

How would I make this selection flat and later modify its elevation? The elevation map is represented in 3 dimensions and is a high-poly, computationally generated product of dronedeploy.
[image: Map that needs modifying]

Comment: For the 2nd part of your question, please add to your question an example of your elevation map data. It might be directly usable (if it's a grayscale displacement map where color value corresponds with height), or might need some scripted conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To flatten a part of your mesh:

1. Go to edit mode.
2. Select the bits you want to flatten.
3. Change the pivot point to "Active Element" through the pivot point menu.
   [image]
4. Deselect and reselect an element (vertex/edge/face) that represents the height for your flattened selected. This will set this element as the active element. The entire mesh will be flattened to this height.
5. Scale to 0 on the Z axis via: <kbd>S</kbd>--><kbd>Z</kbd>--><kbd>0</kbd>.
   [image]

That's it!
[image]