# How to flatten a surface

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, geometry

I'm designing a piece which I will cut out of cardboard in real life. Since the surfaces are curved, I need to flatten them out without changing the dimensions to be able to measure them correctly in the flat cardboard. Here is the surface I want to flatten:

[image]

As you can see, it's slightly curved. I'm almost certain someone has asked the same question, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: This may help https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Paper_Model

Comment: The download button shows me to a wall of text... how do I download that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I flatten a selection of a terrain map?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48017/how-do-i-flatten-a-selection-of-a-terrain-map)

Comment: @EspenSales *Right Click >  Save Link as* or open wall of text and save the page as a python file with `.py`extension